# Woocommerce-How to find if email id has palced order before?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make WP plugin for coupon system. When customer will place order second time i have to give the discount coupon to customer but coupon should only show when customer has already placed one order before.

Now i just want to search from orders , if specific customer already placed order by email_id.

I found one way: [WooCommerce Get Item Meta from All Orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516046/woocommerce-get-item-meta-from-all-orders)

but that way is little bit complicated and make my process slow, tell me if there is any another way. Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the customer id?

Comment: i have only email id example@gmail.com

Comment: Can you access the ID by: `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` and then `echo "User ID: " . $current_user->ID;` if yes, I will give you a quick solution.

Comment: see..suppose if customer not yet logined, how i can get then? its asking for email id on popup

Comment: Then I suppose that you will need to create your own SQL query that will perform the check, or get the user id, if any.

Comment: yes, can you please help on that? i did not get where woocommerce stores order details.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.w3bdeveloper.com/how-to/get-customer-orders-by-email-in-wordpress-woocommerce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve your goal:

```
$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
                    'meta_key'    => '_billing_email',
                    'meta_value'  => $the_order->billing_email,
                    'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
                    'numberposts'=>-1
                ) );
```

And this is how you can loop over the orders:

```
foreach($customer_orders as $k => $v)
{
    $order = new WC_Order( $customer_orders[ $k ]->ID );
    echo 'Order by '.$order->billing_first_name.' '.$order->billing_last_name;
}
```

[Original source](http://www.w3bdeveloper.com/how-to/get-customer-orders-by-email-in-wordpress-woocommerce/)